# Java Assertion in getter method

Tags: java, assertions

Lets say we have this code:

```
Owner owner;
public Owner getOwner(int id)
{
    if (owner == null)
        owner = Owners.getOwner(id);
    assert owner != null;
    return owner;
}
```

What will happen if the Owners.getOwner(id) returns null? will the method die or it will still return null if an assertion is added before the return?

if getOwner(id) is asserted to null will still throw an NPE if getOwner(id).doSomething(); is called?

Comment: ... Depends. Are assertions turned on?

Comment: I use this to run it:

java -Xmx512m -cp

Comment: So you should be able to answer your question then, even if only by *forcing* an assertion, no?

Comment: I actually didn't describe my question well, I just wanted to know if the assertion on a getter will kill a method that returns a value. So in this case even if the owner is null, when I would use getOwner(id).doSomething(); I would not have a NPE since the assertion killed the program.

Comment: I'd still just suggest trying it--but IMO this isn't necessarily a great way to enforce conditions as Joni hints at.

Answer (score 0):

Assertions can be turned on and off to run a program, and are off by default. If they are turned on and their condition is triggered the JVM throws an `AssertionError`. From your comments it seems that you don't have assertions enabled.

Because assertions can go away, you shouldn't base application logic on assertions: if you want to raise an error in a certain unexpected situation, throw an exception.